# Two FKs as one PK in NHibernate-Mapping?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hibernate-mapping

My database looks like this

```
 Role                      Role_AppUser              AppUser
 -------------             -------------             -------------
 |Id         | <-PK        |Id         | <-FK        |UserId     | <-PK
 |Name       |             |UserId     | <-FK        |PreName    |
 |Description|             |xy         |             |SurName    |        
 -------------             -------------             -------------
```

Now I want those 2 FKs of `Role_Appuser` table to become a combined PK. How can I do this with my NHibernate mapping? I'm using mapping-by-code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the mapping you can use a CompositeId:

```
public class Role_AppUserMap : ClassMap<Role_AppUser>
{
   public Role_AppUserMap()
   {
       Table("Role_AppUser")
       CompositeId()
         .KeyProperty(x=>x.RoleId, "Id")
         .KeyProperty(x=>x.UserId, "UserId");
   }
}
```